# starting my console application at background

Tags: c#, watin

My client wanted my C# console application which runs Internet Explorer, to start work as a background window plus the Internet Explorer window that watin opens to be on background.
I use Visual Studio 2005 and watin ver. 2.0.20.1989.
Any answer how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to program anything to accomplish this.  There's a command line that you can use:

```
start /min YourExecutable.exe
```

No need to write anything in your program at all.  This will start *any* regular console application in the background as a minimized window.  See the full documentation for [start](http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm) for more fun options.

Comment: i tried doing it, it didn't opened my console application however it opened my ie from watin.

Comment: Then I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: solved it with WatiN.Core.Settings.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;