# Watin CaptureWebPageToFile() generates black image

Tags: .net, watin

I have a console application running on an application server which uses Watin to automate IE navigation.  When I use the MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false property, all the images created are black.  If I make IE visible, it creates the images fine, but we need to have IE suppressed so it doesn't pop up when people are using the server.

Anyone know of a way to capture screenshots without having the IE window visible?

Comment: You could try the trick mentioned in this other question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314038/starting-my-console-application-at-background

Answer (score 0):

Is this running on a server 2008 instance or Windows 7? Can you run the executable as an administrator? When I run my program that executes .CaptureWebPageToFile() with lower permissions the image comes out all black.